# Recursive and Iterative DFS Algorithm Time Complexity and Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, depth-first-search, space-complexity

So I am having some problems understanding why the time complexity of a recursive DFS and an iterative DFS is the same, perhaps someone can guide me through an easy explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple answer is that they're two different expressions of the same algorithm, so they will have the same time/space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive implementation requires, in the worst case, a number of stack frames (invocations of subroutines that have not finished running yet) proportional to the number of vertices in the graph. This worst-case bound is reached on, e.g., a path graph if we start at one end.

An iterative implementation requires, in the worst case, a number of stack entries proportional to the number of vertices in the graph. The same inputs reach this worst-case time as for the recursive implementation.